# Example for length-prefix framing for protocol buffers

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

I'm currently working on an protocol buffer system for transporting large messages up to 6 Mb. My concern is that I misinterpreted the following post (https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/02/length-prefix-framing-for-protocol-buffers) . My idea of that post is:

```
message GeometryInTime
{
uint32 vecLength = 1;

message Vector3d
{
    optional double x = 1;

    optional double y = 2;

    optional double z = 3;
}

uint32 timeStampLength = 1;
message Timestamp
{ 
    optional int64 seconds = 1;

    optional uint32 nanos = 2;
}
}
```

Is that a valid implementation for the length prefixed system valid? Does it work for repeated fields? Does the length get the serialized length or unserialized ( I'm confusing myself with that )? Does this work for partial message deserialization?

Edit:

```
message Vector3d
{
    optional double x = 1;

    optional double y = 2;

    optional double z = 3;
}

message Timestamp
{ 
    optional int64 seconds = 1;

    optional uint32 nanos = 2;
}

message GeometryInTime
{
    uint32 vecLength = 1;

    optional Vector3d vector = 2;

    uint32 timeStampLength = 3;

    optional Timestamp timestamp = 4;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An embedded `message` is just a definition, not a usage. Right now `GeometryInTime` contains **only** the lengths.

In terms of embedding sub-messages: there are two formats: length-prefixed and grouped (start/end token, this option is basically deprecated now). When using length-prefixed, the library deals with everything - the length will always be "varint" encoded.

The only time custom length prefix approaches is relevant is for the root message - as part of a framing protocol. In that scenario, the library has nothing to do with it, so no amount of changes to the `message` will make any difference: you need to handle the frame data (length prefix etc in whatever format) **outside** of the serializer.

Comment: So if I understood you right, the only relevant length prefix would be for the `GeometryInTime`. There must be a separated (protobuf independent) framing protocol for the root messages.

Comment: You are completely rigtht about my `GeometryInTime` it is wrong it does not have the necessary fields.

Comment: In my edit I repaired my mistake. So my question would be is it posible to deserialize just the vector  and vecLength from the  `GeometryInTime`?

Comment: @MarkoBencik if you only want a partial message: define a message with *just those parts*, and deserialize into that; the binary format won't care